# Jquery Mobile analogs for mobile developing with Phonegap

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

Does we have analogs of Jquery Mobile for mobile developing with Phonegap? I mean not only functionality, but design also? I heard that Jquery Mobile not the best choise for Phonegap from [this article](http://apachecordova.blogspot.ru/2012/11/who-is-murdering-phonegap-its-jquery.html). Does anyone know another frameworks?
And what about design part, which frameworks are best and most popular for Phonegap?

Comment: Everyone is free to have an opinion but in my last 2 years stint with jQM I never had feeling to look for alternatives. You need to implement fast buttons and smooth scroll, rest all is super awesome out of box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically any mobile framework can be used instead of jQuery Mobile.

Probably best ones would be:

- Sencha Touch
- Kendo UI
- Phone JS

Each one has free and commercial version.

Read more about them here: http://www.gajotres.net/top-7-mobile-application-html5-frameworks/

My advice would be Sencha Touch if you like vanilla JavaScript style or Kendo UI if you prefer jQuery.

One last thing, article you read is 2 year old, jQuery Mobile is much much faster now.